# How to have a form and a preview of what the form generates on a small screen?

Tags: forms, preview, screen-real-estate

I am looking at [this webcode.tools page](https://webcode.tools/structured-data-generator/breadcrumb):

[image]

You find this pattern a lot, like with [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/a-simple-share-url-forked-2r35t4?file=%2Findex.js) and other places.

I am thinking of putting ads on the left and right as persistent (320px width each), so there is about 800px of space in the center to put content. How would you design the preview/output along with the form/input so it works nice on such a small screen (which is also the case on a mobile device)? On mobile the ad will be at the bottom and perhaps in between a vertically stacked input/output.

One approach is to just vertically stack the input/output (form/preview). But when editing the form in this case, you can't see what it looks like in realtime which seems to be a killer negative thing in terms of UX. You could instead have the preview front and center, and a button to show a modal or slideout drawer to have the form, but I'm not sure if that extra click would be a detriment to user engagement. And you would have to somehow signify that the button is used to edit the preview, so not sure how that should look so it's obvious yet not too in your face.

Any suggestions / ideas on how to handle this situation?

Comment: In the software industry there is this idea of using the right tool/platform for the right job. What you are doing here is taking a suitable platform and breaking it by subtracting large portions of the screen without adding real value to users. I don't think this question can be answered from a UX point of view. You might need to reconsider your product first, because ads cannot take priority over content from a UX point of view.